# pip is saving packages in the wrong directory

Tags: python, pip, path

I successfully installed packages using pip install; however when running code I get the error that the installed module cannot be found. I understand that this is potentially due to wrong paths/directories but I couldn't find an answer yet how to solve it. Any ideas?

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3>where conda
C:\ProgramData\miniconda\Scripts\conda.exe
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3>where pip
C:\ProgramData\miniconda\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed - and Pythons don't share modules - and conda install modules for one Python but pip install for other Python. See `/full/path/pip -V` to see for what Python it install modules - I see two `pip` on your list and they may work with different Pythons. You may also use `python -m pip ...` to run `pip` for Python which you use to run scripts.

Comment: Create a virtual environment for your project to prevent this from happening...